# Is it possible to store a website on AWS EC2 with ssl using certificate manager

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns

even if my dns records not pointing to aws route53,
someone has tried this before?

What records do I need to add in addition to A?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot use the public ACM certificates directly on your instance as Amazon will only allow this to be deployed to Amazon managed resource such as:

- [Elastic Load Balancer](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/)
- [API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/)
- [CloudFront](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/)

Without one of these services sitting in front of your EC2 you would need to rely on another solution. One of the following would be applicable:

- Free service such as [certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/) allows you to generate a valid SSL that will need to be regenerated every 90 days.
- Buy an SSL and deploy to the hosts.
- Use the paid version of [Amazon ACM Private CA](https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/private-certificate-authority/) (This can become quite expensive).

Route 53 is a DNS configuration service so its responsibility it to control DNS resolution i.e. `example.com` resolves to `1.2.3.4`. HTTPS is a Layer 6/7 operation after DNS has been resolved and you're trying to connect to the application.

You need simply create the DNS records for your application (be that an [A, Alias or CNAME record](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/ResourceRecordTypes.html)). In addition when verifying SSLs the provider would likely ask you to either perform email validation or DNS validation (create a record they provide) to successfully prove ownership.

Comment: Thanks Chris, so I can create ALB in front of my ec2 and use that certificate with that ec2.  I probably just need to add an alias of the ALB to my dns records.   I already approved the ssl, I created an email:  admin@     thank you

Comment: Yes you can add an ALB in front and then use the SSL certificate :)

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :)